# Changing specific value in state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently having issues with changing the "score" keys value, within my data (array of objects) state.

I'll include my code down below, I added ???? at the part where I want to add the code to. Would love some experienced coders insight on this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "./Topic.css"

export default function Topic() {

const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect (() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3002/test')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((actualData) => setData(actualData))
})

return (
<>
<form className='searchContainer' onSubmit={(e) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3002/test/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({title: e.target.topic.value, score: 0})
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
}}>
    <input type="text" name="topic" />
    <button>Add Topic</button>
</form>
<div className='myTopic'>
    {
        data.length > 0 
        ? data.map(({ title, _id, score}) => {
            return (
            <>
            <div className='topicContainer'>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    ????
                }}>Up</button>
                <h3>{score}</h3>
                <button>Down</button>
                <h3 className='topicName'>{title}</h3>
                <h6>Test date</h6>
                {/* <h6>{published_at}</h6> why not showing date? */}
                <button onClick={() => fetch(`http://localhost:3002/test/${_id}`, {method: 'DELETE'})}>Delete</button>
            </div>
            </>
        )
        })
        : <div>No Messages</div>
        }
</div>
</>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the data like the following:

1. add the index in map function call to get an index (position of array).

```
data.map(({ title, _id, score}, ind)
```

2. In setData, we use previous state and update the object by the index above.

```
setData(prevData=>{... ... ... });
```

**Updated code**

```
<div className='myTopic'>
        {
          data.length > 0
            ? data.map(({ title, _id, score}, ind) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <div className='topicContainer'>
                    <button onClick={() => {
                    setData(prevData=>{
                      const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevData));
                      newData[ind].score++;
                      return newData;
                    })
                    }}>Up</button>
                    <h3>{score}</h3>
                    <button>Down</button>
                    <h3 className='topicName'>{title}</h3>
                    <h6>Test date</h6>
                    {/* <h6>{published_at}</h6> why not showing date? */}
                    <button onClick={() => fetch(`http://localhost:3002/test/${_id}`, {method: 'DELETE'})}>Delete</button>
                  </div>
                </>
              )
            })
            : <div>No Messages</div>
        }
      </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help Liki! :)

this is the farthest I've gotten, it looks like it updates the score for a second, and then immediately goes back to the initial value :/

Comment: Please change your useEffect to avoid re-run `useEffect (() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3002/test')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((actualData) => setData(actualData))
}, [])`

Comment: nice THANK YOU!.

it works, but it runs 2 times on one click. do you happen to know why?

Comment: @ashketchup Because your `useEffect` runs on every re-render (After changing data, re-render will be executed and at the same time your hook which fetches data will be called again.

Comment: @ashketchup could you explain more detail what happens on one click?

Comment: I put this on one click: 
onClick={() => {
                    setData(prevData => {
                        const newData = [...prevData];
                        newData[idx].score = newData[idx].score - 1
                        return newData
                    })

so it should add +1 to the score key's value

Comment: in this case -1, since its for a downvote button

Comment: @ashketchup I updated my answer. Because data is an object array, [...prevData] is a shallow copy. We should not change prevState. In old code, whenever newData changed, prevState is also changed. This is an anti-pattern in reactjs. So I made the fresh array copy using JSON.stringify. Please try again. Thanks